# Unit testing Abstract classes in Groovy

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy, mocking

I am new to unit testing and mocking. I am trying to unit test an abstract domain class in Grails. How should I mock an implementation so I can unit test the constraints of the domain class? Is there a way to use the mock libraries that come with groovy or grails? Should I just implement a class that simply extends the abstract class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One cool thing about groovy (among many) is that you can use a map of method names with closures as values to mock out a class.  This includes abstract classes.

```
abstract class Foo {
    def foo() {
       return bar() + 1
    }    

    abstract int bar()
}

def fooInst = [bar: {-> return 1 }] as Foo
assert 2 == fooInst.foo()
```

Comment: What if the abstract class does not have the default constructor?